# Past simple or continuous

Tags: tense, verbs

I would like others to tell me the difference between these sentences.

> It was being a beautiful sunny day.
>    It was a beautiful sunny day.

Comment: The participle **being** emphasizes the *ongoing* aspect of the thing spoken of.    It is grammatical to speak of the day in this manner, but few native speakers would say that the day "was being sunny".

Comment: You may want to consider unaccepting the answer you received, as it has been heavily downvoted, and questions without accepted answers are more likely to get more answers. See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for more details.